# Is push notifications google api/service available for google contacts?

Tags: push-notification, webhooks, google-contacts-api, google-developers-console

In one of my application I have requirement where I want user's google contact update should be instantly sent from his google account to my application for which webhook would be better solution. So want to know where I can get documentation for using webhook with google contacts API. I was able to find it for `user` and `activity` resources but not for `contacts`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As @Blake O'Hare stated, the Google Contacts API documentation doesn't mention anything about a web hook like the Google Calendar API has.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238171/google-contacts-broadcast-push-notification-hook-api) provided a workaround which might help you.

> I think that what you might have to do is the following:
>
> 1. Set up a [database](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mysql_intro.asp) to store
>      your contact's info.
> 2. Create a PHP script which will query Google Contacts for the contact's updated info:
>      a. Use [PHP's curl
>      function](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/CURL_PHP_tutorial) to connect to
>      Google Contacts API query link.
>      b. Set the script to send the
>      credentials requested by [Google Contacts
>      API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters).
>      c. Compare the [contact's
>      information](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) read from the
>      Google Contacts API against the information on that contact stored in
>      your database. If the information is different then update your
>      database.
> 3. Set your script to run periodically:
>        a. If using [Linux](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)
>
>    - Set your server's Cron function to run the script at certain times. 
>      -or-
>         b. If using
>        [Windows](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-198431.html)
>    - Set Windows Task Scheduler to run the script (or a batch file and the script) at certain times.

You can also check this [tutorial](https://capsulecrm.com/support/google-integrations/).

Comment: This would work, but... if a user has thousands of contacts in their google account (like I do) ? Multiply that by the number of users... ouch! that's a lot of requests.

Answer (score 3):

Push notifications are not available for the Contacts API.